# Transferring data to another activity class

Tags: android, json, facebook

I made an android app in which i used the Facebook Login. I want to transfer user's Facebook id to another Activity class. I used the following code to do this

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("fields", "id");
   AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
   asyncRunner.request("me", bundle, new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() {
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            JSONObject jObject;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d("FACEBOOK ID", jObject.getString("id"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I am able to get the Facebook id inside try and catch but when i used this id or transfer it to another activity, it shows and transfer "null".

What should i do to transfer the Facebook id to another activity class?
Please Help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where it the part of the code in which you are passing or stroing the reponse and passing it .

Answer (score 1):

### save your FACEBOOK user id in **Preference** and use it any where... in your Application

store

```
String loginId = jObject.getString("id");

SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

p.edit().putString("FB_ID", loginId).commit();
```

get id in another activity

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String username = p.getString("FB_ID", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete code for storing the id because I don't see an assignment statement. i.e. You haven't stored the value of the "id" you receive anywhere. You just logged it.

Use an assignment statement like

```
String loginId = jObject.getString("id");
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to write the assignment statement here. I have written it in my code. My issue is resolved now by using SharedPreferences,, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Use extras !

For send :

```
int id = 42;
Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
i.putExtra("your_identifient", id);
startActivity(i);
```

For get into your new activiy :

```
int id = -1;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey("your_identifient"))
  id = extras.getInt("your_identifient", -1);
```

Comment: extras.getString() if the id is a string ;)

Comment: I tried that code but didn't work for me. I used SharedPreferences,, it resolved my issue. Thanks for the answer.